How to use Navigate component to capture incoming query string / searchParams?
Currently I have
createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(...)
);

and nested within there is a:
<Route index element={<Navigate to="/raters/start/" />} />

This works fine for the base URL, except that we now need to capture any query strings on the original route and pass those on when we re-route the browser.
Is there something like this functionality available?
<Route
  index
  path="?:queryString"
  element={<Navigate to={`/raters/start?${queryString}`} />}
/>


The URL search string is not used for route path matching, it is invalid to include it in the path prop string. You'll need to manually capture and forward the URL path + searchParams.
Examples:

Custom component
import { Navigate, useSearchParams } from "react-router-dom";

const NavigateWithSearchParams = (props) => {
  const [searchParams] = useSearchParams();

  const newProps = {
    ...props,
    to: {
      // Don't spread `to` prop when it is a string value
      ...(typeof props.to === "string" ? { pathname: props.to } : props.to),
      search: searchParams.toString(),
    },
  };

  return <Navigate {...newProps} />;
};

<Route
  index
  element={<NavigateWithSearchParams to="/raters/start" />}
/>


Read and forward window.location.search
<Route
  index
  element={
    <Navigate
      to={{
        pathname: "/raters/start",
        search: window.location.search,
      }}
    />
  }
/>




Another approach is to use a loader to redirect:
const redirectToRaterStart = async ({ params, request }) => {
  const [, searchParams] = request.url.split("?");
  const policyId = params.policy_id;
  return redirect(
    `/raters/start${policyId ? `/${policyId}` : ""}${
      searchParams ? `?${searchParams}` : ""
    }`
  );
};

<Route index loader={redirectToRaterStart} />
<Route path=":policy_id" loader={redirectToRaterStart} />

